# Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause - update column in same table

Tags: mysql

I know there are a lot of topics on this but I can't figure out how should I rewrite my query to make it work :(
Here my query. It's just should take currency rate from other table and calculate cost

```
update site_s_client_base_price
SET calculated_price_in_base_currency =
SELECT (site_s_currencies.rate * site_s_client_base_price.supplier_price) from
site_s_currencies, site_s_client_base_price
WHERE site_s_currencies.currency_id=site_s_client_base_price.currency_id
```

Please, help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You can't seletc and update in the same table because it's locked, use the example above or use

```
Update TABLE1 t1 set FIELD1= ( select field1 from TABLE1 t2 where .....)
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please? I doesn't try to update the same value I select. I want to take value from one column, multiply it to value from another table and put value in another column of this table

Comment: it's in the same concept, you can't perform a select and an update on a table at the same time, you have to create a temporary table to do that

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can fix this by fixing the subquery.  You don't need to mention the outer table in the inner `from` clause.  You want a correlated subquery:

```
update site_s_client_base_price bp
    SET calculated_price_in_base_currency =
           (SELECT c.rate * bp.supplier_price
            FROM site_s_currencies c
            WHERE c.currency_id = bp.currency_id
           );
```

Comment: Well, now it doesn't complain but doesn't set value also. Always 0 affected rows

Comment: MySQL reports "0 affected rows" when no values change.  Perhaps the values have already been correctly updated.

Comment: Yes @Gordon Linoff it was my mistake. Thank you for your help. Can't vote so :(